Steps needed to move a drive with Debian 12 from BIOS booting computer to a UEFI only booting Computer
I have Debian 12 installed to BIOS boot on SATA drive. The MBR type partitioning was determined by the defaults set in the Debian installer. I wish to move this SATA drive to a different computer which can only UEFI boot. Currently, I can UEFI boot Debian on the existing SATA drive installed on the new computer by doing the following

Turning off secure boot.
Booting first to rEFInd on an external drive.
Having rEFInd instruct the firmware to do a Grubless UEFI boot of Debian.

I would prefer to modify the SATA drive to have an installed Grub UEFI boot Debian. Also, I think the partitioning should be converted to GPT. What are the steps needed to convert to GPT and install a working UEFI booting Grub?
The old computer has 2048 MiB of RAM memory, and the new computer has 4096 MiB of RAM memory. Since the memory is larger, I would like to enlarge the swap space accordingly.
MBR Partition Table Entries



Partition
Device
Boot
StartingSector
EndingSector
Size inSectors
Size
Type
Id




First Primary
/dev/sda1
*
2048
479561485
479559438
228.7 GiB
Linux Filesystem
83


Second Primary
/dev/sda2

479561486
488424194
8862709
4327 MiB
Linux Swap
82



Disk /dev/sda size is 232.9 GiB, 250074470400 bytes, 488426700 sectors @ 512 bytes/sector

This answer requires booting from a Debian 12.7.0 installer. This can be either on a USB flash drive or DVD. This answer uses a DVD. The installation file downloaded from Debian was debian-live-12.7.0-amd64-gnome.iso.
The steps are given below.

UEFI Boot the installer to live Debian.

Open a Terminal application window.
Enter the command below to become the root user.
sudo -s


Convert the MBR partition table to GPT.
When installing a BIOS booting Debian, the installer does not create any partitions in approximately 1 MiB of space after the MBR and at the end of the drive. This allows for easy conversion from a MBR partition table to GPT by entering the commands
sgdisk -g /dev/sda

If successful, then the output will appear as shown below. If the output is different, then there probably was some previous modification which allocate partitions in the space need for the GPT.

***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory.
***************************************************************

The operation has completed successfully.


Create an EFI System partition.
This step also creates a BIOS boot partition so that a BIOS booting Grub can also be installed. (The previous Grub BIOS boot code was overwritten when the GPT was created.)

Note: The Disks application included with the installer can be used in place of GParted application. The Disks application will not FAT32 format the EFI System partition. So, if this is desired, then the mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sda3 command can be used after quitting the Disks application.

Enter the command below to install the GParted application.
apt update
apt install gparted dosfstools mtools

The GParted application will be used to do the following.

Remove the existing 4327 MiB swap partition
Shrink the root partition to increase the following free space to 8914 MiB
Add a 1 MiB BIOS boot partition
Add a 300 MiB EFI System partition
Add a new 8613 MiB Swap partition

Enter the following to open the GParted application.
gparted

Delete highlighted /dev/sda2 partition shown below.

Select the /dev/sda1 partition, as shown below.

Resize the ext4 volume and containing partition so 8914 MiB of free space follows, as shown below.

Select the unallocated space immediately after the /dev/sda1 partition, as shown below.

Create a new 1 MiB partition, as shown below.

Select the unallocated space immediately after "New Partition #1", as shown below.

Create a new 300 MiB fat32 partition, as shown below.

Select the unallocated space immediately after "New Partition #2", as shown below.

Create a new 8613 MiB swap partition, as shown below.

Select the green check mark to "Apply All Operations", as shown below.

Set the flags, as show below, for /dev/sda2. This will change the partition type to BIOS boot.

Set the flags, as show below, for /dev/sda3. This will change the partition type to EFI System.

The result is shown below. Quit the GParted Application.

If necessary, enter the following command to renumber the GPT partitions in ascending order. In the answer, this command was omitted, because the partitions are already in ascending order.
sgdisk -s /dev/sda


Mount the root partition and the EFI System partition.
Enter the commands given below.
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do mount -B $i /mnt/$i; done
chroot /mnt
mkdir -p /boot/efi
mount /dev/sda3 /boot/efi


Update the fstab file.
Enter the command below to view the fstab file.
cat /etc/fstab

Below is an example. The root (/) and swap UUIDs are of the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, where each x is a hexadecimal digit. Below the root and swap UUIDs have be replaced with {root partition UUID} and {original swap UUID}, respectively.
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID={root partition UUID} /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID={original swap UUID} swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0

The swap UUID needs to be updated and the UUID for EFI volume needs to added. The command below outputs the new UUIDs. The EFI UUID is of the form XXXX-XXXX where each X is a hexadecimal digit.
blkid -s UUID /dev/sda3 /dev/sda4

Example output is shown below. The EFI and swap UUIDs have be replaced with {EFI UUID} and {new swap UUID}, respectively.
/dev/sda3: UUID="{EFI UUID}"
/dev/sda4: UUID="{new swap UUID}"

To make the changes to /etc/fstab, you can use nano, some other editor or enter the commands below. When entering the commands below, replace {original swap UUID}, {new swap UUID} and {EFI UUID} with the corresponding actual UUID.
sed 's/{original swap UUID}/{new swap UUID}/' /etc/fstab >fstab
echo UUID={EFI UUID} /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1 >>fstab
mv fstab /etc/fstab

When finish, the command below can be used to view the new fstab file. Note: the {root partition UUID} should be unchanged.
cat /etc/fstab

Below is an example.
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID={root partition UUID} /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID={new swap UUID} swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID={EFI UUID} /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1


Install Grub
Grub is first installed for BIOS booting, then for UEFI booting.
grub-install /dev/sda
apt reinstall grub-efi
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
exit 


Boot to Debian.
Power off the computer. Remove the installation media. Boot to Debian.



The New GUID Partition Table (GPT)
GUID Partition Table (GPT) Entries



#
Device
StartingSector
EndingSector
Size in Sectors
Size
Type
PartitionType GUID




1
/dev/sda1
2048
470171647
470169600
224.2 GiB
Linux Filesystem
0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4


2
/dev/sda2
470171648
470173695
2048
1 MiB
BIOS Boot
21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649


3
/dev/sda3
470173696
470788095
614400
300 MiB
EFI System
C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B


4
/dev/sda4
470788096
488425471
17637376
8612 MiB
Linux Swap
0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F




Contents of the Terminal Window
user@debian:~$ sudo -s
root@debian:/home/user# sgdisk -g /dev/sda

***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

The operation has completed successfully.
root@debian:/home/user# apt update
   .
   .
   .
Lines were omitted for brevity.
   .
   .
   .
root@debian:/home/user# apt install gparts dosfstools mtools
   .
   .
   .
Lines were omitted for brevity.
   .
   .
   .
root@debian:/home/user# gparted
GParted 1.3.1
configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
libparted 3.5
root@debian:/home/user# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
root@debian:/home/user# for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do mount -B $i /mnt/$i; done
root@debian:/home/user# chroot /mnt
root@debian:/# mkdir -p /boot/efi
root@debian:/# mount /dev/sda3 /boot/efi
root@debian:/# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=82e62c10-56ab-43e1-96f8-9d7d959acf66 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=8dc76951-2a26-4636-8f09-f5abfe0ea68c swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
root@debian:/# blkid -s UUID /dev/sda3 /dev/sda4
/dev/sda3: UUID="9895-777C"
/dev/sda4: UUID="fedd73b8-b677-4f32-a931-bfac0cbc12c4"
root@debian:/# sed 's/8dc76951-2a26-4636-8f09-f5abfe0ea68c/fedd73b8-b677-4f32-a931-bfac0cbc12c4/' /etc/fstab >fstab
root@debian:/# echo UUID=9895-777C /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1 >>fstab
root@debian:/# cat fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=82e62c10-56ab-43e1-96f8-9d7d959acf66 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=fedd73b8-b677-4f32-a931-bfac0cbc12c4 swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=9895-777C /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
root@debian:/# mv fstab /etc/fstab
root@debian:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@debian:/# apt reinstall grub-efi
   .
   .
   .
Lines were omitted for brevity.
   .
   .
   .
root@debian:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@debian:/# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-25-amd64
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
root@debian:/# exit
exit
root@debian:/home/user# exit
exit
user@debian:~$ 


Debian Installer Default Swap Space Size
The table below shows the default sizes chosen for the swap space by the Debian installer. From small amounts of RAM memory, the swap space is a little more than twice the amount of RAM. For large amounts of RAM, the swap space is a little more than the actual amount of RAM.



RAM Memory
Swap Space




2048 MiB
4327 MiB ≃ 4.23 GiB


4096 MiB
8.41G ≃ 8613 MiB


8192 MiB
9011 MiB ≃ 8.8 GiB


12288 MiB
12.85 GiB ≃ 13157 MiB



